# Link two tables in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this two following table :

```
|**Machines**|    |**Parts**|
|idMachine   |    |idPart   |
|label       |    |label    |
```

I would like to link this two tables knowing that one machine can have multiple parts and one part can composed multiple machines.

At the end, It will be use in a web form: when a user choose a machine, I display the different parts linked to the chosen machine.

Do I have to create another table to link this two tables or I can simply write a SQL request ? Or any other solutions?

Comment: Yes you need to create a thrid table where the fields will be at least idMachine and idPart. In general a many to many relation requires a third table for linking the two tables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a many to many relationship, then yes you need a 3rd table to create the relationship. This table will often only hold the ID's of the respective rows that that in the table, with both being a composite primary key (to avoid duplication). Something like this:

```
--Sample tables
CREATE TABLE dbo.Machine (MachineID int IDENTITY NOT NULL,
                          Label nvarchar(50));

ALTER TABLE dbo.Machine ADD CONSTRAINT PK_MachineID PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (MachineID);
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.Part (PartID int IDENTITY NOT NULL,
                       Label nvarchar(50));

ALTER TABLE dbo.Part ADD CONSTRAINT PK_PartID PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (PartID);
GO
--Relationship table
CREATE TABLE dbo.MachinePart (MachineID int NOT NULL,
                              PartID int NOT NULL);
--Add Primary Key
ALTER TABLE dbo.MachinePart ADD CONSTRAINT PK_MachinePartID PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (MachineID,PartID);

--Add Foreign Keys
ALTER TABLE dbo.MachinePart ADD CONSTRAINT FK_MachinePart_MachineID FOREIGN KEY (MachineID) REFERENCES dbo.Machine(MachineID);
ALTER TABLE dbo.MachinePart ADD CONSTRAINT FK_MachinePart_PartID FOREIGN KEY (PartID) REFERENCES dbo.Part(PartID);
GO
--Clean up
DROP TABLE dbo.MachinePart
DROP TABLE dbo.Part;
DROP TABLE dbo.Machine;
```

Comment: You could add a quantity column, or similar, @mikey . I said *"This table will often only hold the ID's of the respective rows that that in the table"* not that it **must** contain only those 2 columns. Some do contain additional meta data.

Comment: *"Having a fixed amount of columns"* Where does this have a fixed number of columns..? A Table can have up to 1024. I don't understand your point here. What's so hard about adding a `Quantity` column to the `MachinePart` table? It's literally `ALTER TABLE dbo.MachinePart ADD Quantity tinyint;`

Comment: You `INSERT` a new row for every part, @mikey .... That is the basics of normalisation. You don't have `part1`, `part2`, `part3`, columns as that is denormalised *would* suffer the problem you are describing. The above would allow a machine to have **every** part.

Comment: ... Again, @mikey, it's not hard to add a `Quantity` column... As I showed before it's just *`ALTER TABLE dbo.MachinePart ADD Quantity tinyint;`* Then it's as simple as `INSERT INTO dbo.MachinePart (MachineID, PartID, Quanity) VALUES (1,1,2)`... I don't see the problem here. I have never said that the above it limited to 2 columns, only you have said that.

Answer (score 0):

You need common factor in both table to link the tables or write a SQL to identify , particular machine associates with these parts or parts are associated with such machines.

If you elaborate, what are the attributes are available in both tables? apart from which you listed those seems not sufficient to link both tables.